# Tkinter - Entry Widget Not Taking Input

Tags: python, user-interface, windows-7, tkinter

My Tkinter GUI on Windows is acting strange. It has an Entry widget to accept some text, however when I click on it to set the focus, it does not respond. But if change the window focus from the GUI to any other window and then back to the GUI, the cursor shows on the entry widget.

Can anyone help me fix this bug? I tried setting `self.entry.focus()`, but to no avail.

My code is simply:

```
# Text Input
self.text = Entry(data_frame, width=30)
self.text.grid(row=0, column=1)
self.text.focus()
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Added the code. Pretty straightforward, hence can't understand the bug. :(

Comment: it sounds like an issue with tk itself. Which windows version and which python are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 with Python 2.7.5.

Comment: I don't program in Windows, so I can't help you further. But you should check if it is not already a know issue. Also try a different Python version. If you post your whole code, I could try it on Linux and tell you if it is your code...

Comment: @Oz123 you can fork my code from https://github.com/varunagrawal/WaterFont

Comment: @Oz123 I coded this up in Linux, and it works perfectly there. Hence the reason for this question.

Comment: I cloned your program from github and ran it OSX and it seems to work, though it starts with a directory dialog rather than a window with an entry widget. Can you reduce this to a small working example? Obviously, the code in the question is non-working code so you're leaving something out.

Comment: @BryanOakley That is the complete software. All you have to do is select a directory with images in it. Then you'll get the complete GUI.

Comment: @VarunAgrawal: my comment about the code was referring to the actual question on this site -- you didn't post enough code to duplicate the problem. Most people don't want to take the time to clone a whole repository and dig through a half dozen files or more looking for a bug. Try to create a small, reproducible case. Often, that exercise is enough for you to discover the bug on your own.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am getting what you are saying, but I think the problem is in the Windows Tkinter only since it works fine on my Linux machine. Will add a small demo program nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

I ran your code under Debian Wheezy, and I don't see any problem with it. 
This could be a problem with TK itself under Windows.

For a more modern Toolkit, you should really consider using PyGTK and\or PyQT. Both work perfectly on Linux and Windows, and provide more for less lines of code.

Sorry, I know this is not a real answer. But it seems your coding problem is not a problem with your code.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the effort. I developed the entire code under Ubuntu Linux, and ran thorough tests, thus I was quite surprised at this error. The thing is, I need a lightweight GUI toolkit for Python that is cross-platform and does not require additional installs, hence Tk. I hope this problem is only on my Windows machine.